# Inherit template without using super()

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following `base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/base.css') }}" type = "text/css"/>
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have `base_header.html`, which I want for pages with a header

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/header.css') }}" type = "text/css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<header>
...
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

In order for the header to show up, I have to call `super()` in both blocks

```
{% extends "base_header.html" %}

{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<title>Page title</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{{ super() }}
<h1>Page header</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to have this sort of template inheritance without having to include `super()` every time I want to include the header? I would like it so if I decide a page needs a header, I can just change `extends "base.html"` to `extends "base_header.html"` without further changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `super()` call, because otherwise your final template is *replacing* the content of the `head` block in the parent template. You could introduce a new block in the intermediate template, `base_header.html`:

```
{% block head %}

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/header.css') }}" type = "text/css"/>
{% block more_head %}
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then your final template looks like:

```
{% extends "base_header.html" %}

{% block more_head %}
<title>Page title</title>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for as I'd still need to change every template which inherits from `base_header` from `head` to `more_head`, but I to be able to change parent template without having to modify the children.